# VCal time change with change in system time zone

Tags: outlook, vcal

In my application, a mail sended with attachment of Vcal for add booking in Microsoft Outlook but server in different time zone and client in different time zone so vcal time change accoring to current Outlook time zone.
 If I set same time zone on both server and client then vcal show corret time.
My current format of vcal as:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:1.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20100712T191500Z
DTEND:20100712T194500Z
SUMMARY:Meditation with FNF LNL
DESCRIPTION:You have booked an appointment.
LOCATION:Tech Site 1 (Marriott Room1)
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Please suggest any format of vcal so it independent on outlook time zone.

I add **DTSTART** time in vb.net

```
startDate.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMdd\THHmmss\Z")
```

Is any format in vcal so it independent on time zone

Answer (score 0):

These dates/times should be in GMT and should work across timezones.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the 'Z' at the end of the start and end times.